# Powershell: Dynamic Menu-based program to copy file

Tags: powershell, menu, copy-item

The purpose of this was to copy one (or more) files from one user selected dynamic location to another user selected dynamic location.

```
Write-Host "Choose where to copy FROM"

$1MainFolder = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\FROM" -Directory | Sort-Object)
$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $1MainFolder.count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($1MainFolder[$i-1].name)"
    $menu.Add($i,($1MainFolder[$i-1].name))
    }

[int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
$selection = $menu.Item($ans)
# The directory after the selection is only one, however it's different for every user; this remains the same for "COPY TO"
$First = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\FROM\$selection" -Directory)

# This directory is the same for every user; this remains the same for "COPY TO"
$DataFROM = (Set-Location $First\USERFILE) 

Clear-Host


Write-Host "Choose where to copy TO"

$2MainFolder = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\TO" -Directory | Sort-Object)
$menu2 = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $2MainFolder.count; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$i. $($2MainFolder[$i-1].name)"
    $menu2.Add($i,($2MainFolder[$i-1].name))
    }

[int]$ans2 = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
$selection2 = $menu2.Item($ans2)
$Second = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\TO\$selection2" -Directory)

$DataTO = (Set-Location $Second\USERFILE)

Clear-Host
```

That completes section one and two. The third section allows the user to then pick the file they want copied - this is a separate function which works well, however it errors in conjunction with this. I've since simplified the function to obtain the same error with:

```
# The Select-Object section being the simplified part...
Get-ChildItem $DataFROM | Select-Object "DATA.log*"  | Copy-Item -Destination $DataTO
```

What I expect to happen is for the data to be copied from the initial dynamic location to the final dynamic destination.

What happens is that I get an error stating that it "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string." to which it points at the $DataTO variable.

This then lead me to disregard the third section and test the variables to which I found that if I use the following after the first two sections:

```
Get-ChildItem $DataFROM

# or

Get-ChildItem $DataTO
```

it returns back information from the last selected menu, disregarding the variables entirely. So then are the dynamic menus not to be used in this manner or perhaps I am using the menus wrong?

Would someone please advise where I've gone astray?

Comment: Have you considered using [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog) and [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog) for this?

Comment: My apologizes for the delayed response. After writing a test version with your suggestion and giving it to my test-users, they found it to be less intuitive compared to what I previously had. In addition, the tree menu for the folderbrowserdialog hid behind other applications that were open, as such they didn't know what to do.

It might help to add that the people I'm making this for spend their time on AS400 systems and aren't too comfortable messing with GUI components. Hence why the strictly defined wording within Powershell was more their speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I've since re-worked it to the following that fits my requested needs: (hopefully this will aid someone else needing something similar)

```
[array]$sMainFolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\DATA-TO_FROM" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
          Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
              $found = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'USERFILE' } | Select-Object -First 1
              if ($found) {
                  [PSCustomObject]@{
                      RootFolder = [string]$_.FullName
                      Path = $found.FullName
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      [array]$dMainFolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\DATA-TO_FROM" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        $subs = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName
        $found = $subs | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.FullName } | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'USERFILE' } | Select-Object -First 1
            if ($found) {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    RootFolder = [string]$_.FullName
                    Path = $found.FullName
                }
            }
        }

function ShowMenu ($Folders, $Message) {
    Write-Host $Message
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $Folders.count; $i++) {
        $name = $Folders[$i - 1].RootFolder
        Write-Host "$i. $name"
    }
    [int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter Selection'
    Return $Folders[$ans -1].Path
}

$DataFROM = ShowMenu $sMainFolder "Choose where to copy FROM"
$DataTO = ShowMenu $dMainFolder "Choose where to copy TO"

Clear-Host

Copy-Item "$DataFROM\*" $DataTO -Recurse -Force
```